# Conversion table b/w older & newer ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm porting a program that was written 2 years ago based on ROS 0.4 to the newer version, and not to mention seeing a bunch of compile errors due to the API incompatibility. Is there a document that shows conversion between older and newer ROS ? I'm using electric but diamondback would do too.

Thanks.

**Update 9/21/11**) One example out of hundreds of missing API is `deprecated_msgs::RobotBase2DOdom.stall`. I'm now using `nav_msgs::Odometry` in place of `RobotBase2DOdom` but haven't been able to figure out `stall` equivalent yet (this isn't a question though).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11261/conversion-table-b/w-older-&-newer-ros/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2011-09-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-09-21**:
A new question makes sense. Ken already answered your original question as well as it can be.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-09-21**:
@joq thanks. I just updated the question body text (though I wonder if I should ask another question for this particular case).

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-09-20**:
Just FYI, there should be very little difference between diamondback and electric for most APIs.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-09-20**:
I know of no general document. Each API should describe its own changes over time. Specifically, what compile errors are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS 0.4 is quite old -- that's a bit long for any docs to exist.  In general, the release notes for each ROS Distribution should provide the major migration notes if you click on the relevant change lists.  For Electric->Diamondback, there's very little changes for ROS code, though thirdparty libraries like Eigen require more significant migration.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/cturtle

http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback

http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2